# Mixing pandas and spark - is spark still been fully utilised?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My question is more generic than anything else. I have been unable to find an answer to this so far.

If a Notebook containing Python code contains mixed Spark, with pandas, is Spark still been fully utlised? For example, you may begin with the following:

```
df = spark.sql(...)
df = df.toPandas()
```

Then in another module, the pandas package is used to manipulate the dataframe (i.e. pd.merge(...)), the output of this manipulation used at the end like so:

```
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

If this is incorrect then I assume it is necessary to use `pyspark.pandas`. Or is my assumption correct?

Comment: The moment you run `toPandas()`, it just creates a pandas dataframe that runs on your driver. So, your spark cluster is not used for the computations that you do after `toPandas()` and before your `spark.createDataFrame(df)` call.

Comment: If the `df.toPandas()` call returns a VERY large dataframe, this could be risky because it is possible that your driver may run out of memory (since `pandas` keeps the dataframe in memory on your driver). You can indeed use `pyspark.pandas` to perform your intermediate calculations but beware that sometimes it throws the `NotImplementedError` for things that are implemented in `pandas` but not in `pyspark.pandas`.

Comment: Depending on what kind of operations you are performing (and the amount of data you're working with), I would recommend trying to rewrite your pandas dataframes operations so that you are instead using pyspark dataframes. For example, something like a merge operation can also be done with pyspark dataframes and in general, `df.toPandas()` is discouraged because you lose the parallelization that you would otherwise achieve with pyspark dataframe operations